# continuity after taking partial derivative

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Suppose $f:(x,y)\in K\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function (in $x$ and $y$) and $K$ is a compact set. If $f$ is continuously differentiable in $y$. Is $f_y$ still continuous in $x$?

---

I am not sure whether it is correct or under what condition it is correct. Briefly speaking, if $f$ is continuously differentiable in $y$, then for any $x\in K$, I have
$$
f(x,y+h)=f(x,y)+f_y(x,y)h+o(h),
$$
as $h\to0$.
I would like $f_y(x,y)$ to be bounded for all $x\in K$ and $|y|\le C$, and a sufficient condition is to show $f_y$ is still continuous in $x$.

Comment: It is ambiguous to me. Perhaps the context would clarify?

Comment: @copper.hat I have added some explanations on how I come up with the problem.

Comment: It depends on what is meant by continuously differentiable in $y$. Does that mean that the restricted function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable or that the function $(x,y) \mapsto {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y}$ is continuous?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean for each $x\in K$, $y\to f(x,y)$ is differentiable and $y\to f_y(x,y)$ is continuous.

Comment: This is not as straightforward as I thought it would be :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{|x|} \arctan {y \over x},& x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} = \begin{cases} {\sqrt{|x|} \over x^2+y^2},& x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then, for a fixed $x$, the function $y \mapsto {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y}$ is continuous,
but $x \mapsto {\partial f(x,0) \over \partial y}$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: is the original $f$ continuous at $0$?

Comment: @John: Sure, you have $|f(x,y)| \le {\pi \over 2} \sqrt{|x|}$.